# PHP file() UTF-8 Handling

Tags: php

I have IFTTT Webhook on PHP page. I use file() to trigger IFTTT Webhook:

```
$ifttturl = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/1234/with/key/xxxxxxxxxx?value1=test";
```

It works normal. When I use some special chars (like ş, ğ in ISO-8859-9), I get such these: þ ð when it triggers for ex. Google Sheets.

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9", "test şçğ");
$tempStr = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/1234/with/key/xxxxxxxxxx?value1=".$text;
$ifttturl = file($tempStr);
```

Comment: Did you try using `urlencode`? Also, is your PHP file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, I tried header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); and urlencode but could not find a solution.